# Error in setting proper dimensions for table

Tags: tables

Here is my effort to generate this table. I wanted to know why I get an error? error is "undefined the sequence". Alternatively, any better format is welcome to tabulate following sample data.

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=10cm}
  \caption{Initial, post-etch and post SPM treatment heights.}
  \label{tab:2}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{3}{S[table-format=4.0]}}
    \toprule
           {Wafer \#} & {Initial height} & {Post-etch height}&{Post SPM treatment} &{SPM treatment}$ \\
            & \si{\mu m} & \si{\mu m} &\si{nm}\\
    \midrule
     $Length (mm)$  &       1.4725 &        1.5875 &        142.5 & 112\\
     $Width (mm)$     &      1.4725 &        1.575&        142.5& 113 \\
     $Thickness (mm)$   &       1.495 &        1.5925&        132.5& 145 \\
     $Young modulus (GPa))$  &       1.492 &        1.66 &        190& 456\\
     $Young modulus (GPa)$    &       1.465 &        1.63&        197.5& 5454 \\
     $TYoung modulus (GPa)$    &       1.2525 &        1.4625&        192.5 & 543\\
      $Young modulus (GPa)$    &       1.2525 &        1.4625&        192.5& 903 \\
       $Boundary conditions$    &       1.2525 &        1.4625&        192.5& 5353 \\
        $Applied load$    &       1.2525 &        1.4625&        192.5& 434 \\
         $Young modulus (GPa)$    &       1.2525 &        1.4625&        192.5& 5345 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: it is impossible to say what is wrong if you only post a small fragment. You use several non-standard commands such as `\toprule` and `S`  and `\captionsetup` have you loaded packages to define them (probably bookmarks,  siunitx and caption) also the first column loks very wrong, why the `$`? Also you have specified 4 columns table but have 5 entries in each row.

Comment: Please do not use `$$` to put something in italic. This will mess with the font spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please add another column.  Yes, packages were loaded. Can you post a demo for above data, it seems that my code is a bit mess. Thanks.

Comment: No sorry it is your question it is up to _you_ to post an example that  people can run to generate an error. You say you have an undefined command error how can we guess what that is if you don't say? `\toprule` will give that error if you have not loaded booktabs  that would be my guess.

Comment: The exact error message tells the name of the undefined control sequence. From the used macros I assume, that packages `booktabs`, `caption` and `siunitx` are needed. Also the data lines show five columns, but only four columns are declared (with a wrong value for `table-format`). Also the text in the first column should not be set in math mode.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek as you are here... did you see the github message about zref? (I'll delete this comment in a bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, note the loaded packages and the changes to the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\captionsetup{width=10cm}
\caption{Initial, post-etch and post SPM treatment heights.}
\label{tab:2}

\begin{tabular}{
  l 
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=3.1]
  S[table-format=4.0]
}
\toprule
{Wafer \#} & {Initial} & {Post-etch} & {Post SPM}  & {SPM} \\
           & {height}  & {height}    & {treatment} & {treatment} \\
  & \si{\micro\meter}
  & \si{\micro\meter}
  & \si{\nano\meter} \\
\midrule
Length (\si{mm})          & 1.4725 & 1.5875 & 142.5 &  112 \\
Width (\si{mm})           & 1.4725 & 1.575  & 142.5 &  113 \\
Thickness (\si{mm})       & 1.495  & 1.5925 & 132.5 &  145 \\
Young modulus (\si{GPa})  & 1.492  & 1.66   & 190   &  456 \\
Young modulus (\si{GPa})  & 1.465  & 1.63   & 197.5 & 5454 \\
TYoung modulus (\si{GPa}) & 1.2525 & 1.4625 & 192.5 &  543 \\
Young modulus (\si{GPa})  & 1.2525 & 1.4625 & 192.5 &  903 \\
Boundary conditions       & 1.2525 & 1.4625 & 192.5 & 5353 \\
Applied load              & 1.2525 & 1.4625 & 192.5 &  434 \\
Young modulus (\si{GPa})  & 1.2525 & 1.4625 & 192.5 & 5345 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ egreg: If I want to type text in one of the row how should change the format from numeric to text in a specific row?

Comment: @user107832 Just like you do in the header: `{text}` in braces.

Comment: It does not accept. Just try and type TEXT instead of one of number. Also, if the number is bigger or shorter they will not look like in order but also they will displaced in rows and columns.

Comment: @user107832 Did you add the braces? For the numbers, you specify `table-format=a.b`, where `a` is the maximum number of digits in the integral part and `b` is the maximum number of digits in the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this, using in addition `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs, caption, makecell}
\DeclareSIUnit\micron{\micro\metre}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\upshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=10cm}\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
  \caption{Initial, post-etch and post SPM treatment heights.}
  \label{tab:2}
  \begin{tabular}{ @{}>{\itshape}l *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}S[table-format=3.1]S[table-format=4.0]}
    \toprule
           {\thead{Wafer \#\\ (\si{\micron})}} & {\thead{Initial height\\ (\si{\micron})}} & {\thead{Post-etch \\ height  (\si{\micron})}}
            & {\thead{Post SPM\\ treatment  (\si{\nm})}} & {\thead{SPM\\ treatment}} \\
    \midrule
     Length (mm) & 1.4725 & 1.5875 & 142.5 & 112\\
     Width (mm) & 1.4725 & 1.575& 142.5& 113 \\
     Thickness (mm) & 1.495 & 1.5925& 132.5& 145 \\
     Young modulus (GPa) & 1.492 & 1.66 & 190& 456\\
     Young modulus (GPa) & 1.465 & 1.63& 197.5& 5454 \\
    TYoung modulus (GPa) & 1.2525 & 1.4625& 192.5 & 543\\
     Young modulus (GPa) & 1.2525 & 1.4625& 192.5& 903 \\
     Boundary conditions & 1.2525 & 1.4625& 192.5& 5353 \\
     Applied load & 1.2525 & 1.4625& 192.5& 434 \\
     Young modulus (GPa) & 1.2525 & 1.4625& 192.5& 5345 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bernard, units should not be italic.

Comment: I made an exception, because the rest of the column is italic. But if you don't want it, the best is to use `\si{\GPa}` and `\si{\mm}`.